# browser supporting for HTML5 and JQuery mobile application

Tags: jquery, html

any specific browser will support for html5 and jquery mobile application?

While creating mobile application, JQuery and HTML5 both are required?

Comment: What is your question? Are you looking for a mobile browser which supports HTML5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [HTML 5 browser support matrix](http://caniuse.com/). (Follow the link, then click on the *Tables* tab. The columns to the far right show the respective mobile browser capabilities.)

jQuery is a JavaScript library and is indepedent of HTML 5. It is supported by every browser that supports current JavaScript.

To create mobile applications you neither need HTML 5 nor jQuery.

Also have a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), which is a jQuery library aimed specifically at mobile devices.